# ImportError: No module named PyMesh

Tags: python, installation

I have tried installing `pymesh` on both Mac OS and Windows, by downloading the source and installing using `python setup.py install` (as described in https://github.com/qnzhou/PyMesh).

In both cases, when I then ran the test code: `python -c "import pymesh; pymesh.test()"`, I get an ImportError. E.g., in Windows, I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymesh2-0.1.14-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\pymesh\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
from .Mesh import Mesh
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymesh2-0.1.14-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\pymesh\Mesh.py", line 5, in <module>
import PyMesh
ImportError: No module named PyMesh
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, don't be worried. If you use the virtual environment to manage the python version. 
So you can solve this problem by the following:

```
cd $PYMESH_PATH
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.2.0/lib/libpython3.6m.dylib -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.2.0/include/python3.6m -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.2.0/bin/python ..
make -j
cd ..
python setup.py install
```

You can also refer to [this](https://github.com/PyMesh/PyMesh/issues/141).

This solved my problem.

Good Luck!!