# Python, pymesh install problem on windows10

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I'm a Python newbie trying to program python using pymesh library but I cant get it to install properly.
Accordijng to attached image I have installed it, and the package says its for 3.8.x and I have python 3.8.2 installed.
pymesh installation instructions (https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) say to run a test after installing the package. The test fails.

```
(work) (base) D:\Downloads\HoleCutter>python -c "import pymesh; pymesh.test()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'pymesh' has no attribute 'test'
```

I dont have the resources/capability to 'build packages with cmake'
[screen snap from command prompt window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc11r.png)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the PyMesh library isn't kept up to date on PIP, instead you have to use Docker or compile it yourself. This problem is covered by the following issue on Github, however no action has been taken for years: https://github.com/PyMesh/PyMesh/issues/94

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried "pip install pymesh" or "pipx.x install pymesh"?
I think the instructions in the link you provided are for Linux and Mac OS. You can look at this link: [ImportError: No module named PyMesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205891/importerror-no-module-named-pymesh)

Comment: "Pip install pymesh" installs an entirely different library than the one the user is looking for