# PyMesh problems with Setup on Windows10 and Error using Docker Version

Tags: windows, installation, pymesh

I want to install PyMesh on a Windows 10 PC, if possible it should be installed in the side-packages of an interpreter delivered with the IDE we use.

I tried the way to run the setup discribed here
https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

so the part :
git clone https://github.com/PyMesh/PyMesh.git
cd PyMesh
git submodule update --init
worked without any problems.

I am not sure on windows if I now just can write
set PYMESH_PATH =  path
and if i can use the path "...\PyMesh\PyMesh" here?
so i left out this part

I installed numpy and scipy (allready installed)
and nose because it is mentioned in the requirements.txt.
So my numpy scipy and nose versions are
numpy 1.19.1
scipy 1.6.0
nose 1.3.7 (same as requirenments)

and just run the setup.py with admin rights
python .\setup.py install
which also seemed to work but i got an error trying
python -c "import pymesh; pymesh.test()"
from the PyMesh folder
saying ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyMesh'

or if i go up one Folder doing the same
saying AttributeError: module 'PyMesh' has no attribute 'triangle'

I found this link [ImportError: No module named PyMesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205891/importerror-no-module-named-pymesh)
but i just dont know what i should type in there

I tried to install via pip by using pip install pymesh
but pip Installer gives me a different library.

So i tried in the docker version and in docker i tried the pymesh.load_mesh method with an stl File
but got
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

I dont know if this is just the stl format (expecting binary getting ascii or vice versa)
The stl file itself can be opened so shouldnt be corrupted.

So is there a different way to install pymesh? A wheel would be great. Is it possible to install pymesh to the side-packages of a given Interpreter? Did someone else allready had the same error in Docker and knows the issue

thank you for your help